# How to use the connections.json file of Logic Apps (Single-tenant) project based on the environment in Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I have gone through the [Logic Apps (Single - tenant)](https://github.com/Azure/logicapps/tree/master/azure-devops-sample) documentation and then created single tenant logic app workflows using visual studio code. The created project structure contains the `connections.json` and `local.settings.json` files which contains the connections details of workflows.

I want to read the values  from custom `settings.json (appsettings.json)` file instead of `local.settings.json` and then use those values in `connections.json` file. Also, I want to   change these settings per environment wise in Azure DevOps release pipeline. So, can you please suggest me how to do it in Azure DevOps release pipeline?

Comment: I'm also struggling with this, I wonder did you get anywhere?

Comment: @JasonHyland, Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68888469/how-to-parameterize-the-values-in-workflow-json-and-connections-json-files-of-az stackoverflow question.