# How to use Azure DevOps to deploy Azure Logic App (Standard)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I can now use the ARM template task to successfully deploy the Azure logic app (Consumption). In the Consumption mode, I can export the complete arm template (including the set variables and the set workflow) in the Azure logic app.

But when I try to export the arm template in **Standard** Azure logic app mode, the exported arm template doesn't contain the variables and workflow I added in Standard Azure logic app, so when I deploy using Arm template in Azure DevOps, I can't Deploy variables and workflows into the logic app.

**My question is: How to deploy Azure Logic app(Standard) in Azure DevOps?**

By the way: this official documentation is not suitable for our needs, we are dragging and dropping the workflow in the Azure logic app instead of building it locally.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/set-up-devops-deployment-single-tenant-azure-logic-apps?source=recommendations&tabs=azure-devops#deploy-infrastructure

Appreciate any insight

Comment: have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68890865/4167200

Answer (score 1):

You want to deploy using Azure DevOps to I assume you have you ARM templates in a repo there. What you need to do is to download the JSON code for each workflow, along with the Schemas and Maps you are using, and store them in your repo. Then you use Zip-deployment as in the article you referenced.

The structure to use is shown below. Each workflow is stored in a separate folder with a unique name, but the file for JSON code should always be called workflow.json

|- name-of-first-workflow
|- workflow.json
|- name-of-second-workflow
|- workflow.json
|- name-of-third-workflow
|- workflow.json
|- Schemas
|- first-schema.xsd
|- second-schema.xsd
|- Maps
|- first-map.xslt
|- second-map.xslt

The fundamental difference is that LA Consumption only have one workflow, but a LA Standard can have many workflows. You should consider the workflows are source code, not as infrastructure-as-code.

Comment: From what I've seen so far I have come to the same conclusion that Standard/Single-tenant workflows are source code rather than IaC, and should therefor be treated as such. In fact, under the hood, it looks like LA standard is just an Azure Function, meaning we should treat it that way in terms of CI/CD, instead of the way we treat consumption Logic Apps (e.g. ARM templates etc). However, that's just a conclusion I've drawn on my own. Do you know if Microsoft has explicitly expressed this somewhere in their documentation? I don't feel that they make this distinction abundantly clear.